# Removing a node from Node-red

Tags: node-red

I've installed the contrib-mssql node using npm -g.
Now when I run npm uninstall the node is still listed in the left side bar.

- There are no flows using it and I can disable it in user settings/manage palette.
- Also I did not find anything referring to "mssql" in the settings.json of Red-Node.

I like to get rid of the node. Any hints on what I could try next?

Comment: If you installed the node globally (-g) then you need to include the -g when you uninstall it as well.

Comment: I did that and double checked now. I wonder, is settings file the only place where NR keeps a list of available nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED keeps a cache of all the discovered nodes in the a file called `.config.json` in the user directory (normally `~/.node-red/` on unix style systems).

This file also contains the key to decrypt the credentials file. If you have no credentials stored in your flow (this is unlikely if you are connecting out to any other systems) then you can try removing the file.

Instead you can rename the file, start Node-RED let it start up, shut it down then copy the `_credentialSecret` value from the old file to the new file and restart Node-RED. This should move refresh the cache and allow access to the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Some remains of the node package could be found under folder npm/node_modules/node-red/node_modules. Deleting the folder made the node vanish.